# How do I console log every name in an array using a forEach method and a callback as my only argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback

I'm given an array called "names". Using a forEach method and a callback as its only argument, how do I console log every item in the array?

I've tried creating a "for" loop. But that's not what the problem asked for. Although the question is pretty straightforward, I'm just not sure what I'm missing

```
namesArray.forEach (callback); 
console.log(names);
```

The error message says "expected 0 to be 5" I'm expecting the entire array to appear

Comment: What language is this? Looks like javascript or typescript. If you add the "javascript" tag you'll get lots more useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like so:

```js
const namesArray = ["John", "Jack", "James"];
const callback = elem => console.log(elem);
namesArray.forEach(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines a bit, I suspect the answer you're looking for is something like this:

```js
namesArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
namesArray.forEach(elt => console.log(elt));
```

You can see the callback is an arrow function that prints the element to the console.

*For more about the `forEach()` method, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).*